# Google App Engine and Laravel, some bug?

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy my laravel app into the GCS (Google Cloud Storage).

While doing a deployment:

```
gcloud preview app deploy ./app.yaml --project="cuisinedegeek-151614"
```

I got these errors:

> WARNING: The `gcloud preview app` command group is deprecated; please use the `gcloud app` commands instead.
>
> ERROR: The [application] field is specified in file [/home/epistolshow/CuisineDeGeek/app.yaml]. This field is not used by gcloud and must be removed. Project name should instead be specified either by `gcloud config set project MY_PROJECT` or by setting the `--project` flag on individual command executions.
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Errors occurred while parsing the App Engine app configuration.
>   epistolshow@cuisinedegeek-151614:~/CuisineDeGeek$ gcloud app deploy ./app.yaml --project="cuisinedegeek-151614"
>
> ERROR: The [application] field is specified in file [/home/epistolshow/CuisineDeGeek/app.yaml]. This field is not used by gcloud and must be removed. Project name should instead be specified either by `gcloud config set project MY_PROJECT` or by setting the `--project` flag on individual command executions.
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Errors occurred while parsing the App Engine app configuration.
>   epistolshow@cuisinedegeek-151614:~/CuisineDeGeek$ gcloud app deploy ./app.yaml --project="cuisinedegeek-151614"
>   ERROR: The [application] field is specified in file [/home/epistolshow/CuisineDeGeek/app.yaml]. This field is not used by gcloud and must be removed. Project name should instead be specified either by `gcloud config set project MY_PROJECT` or by setting the `--project` flag on individual command executions.
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Errors occurred while parsing the App Engine app configuration.
>   epistolshow@cuisinedegeek-151614:~/CuisineDeGeek$

Which doesn't make sense because app.yaml:

```
    runtime: php55

    handlers:

    - url: /favicon\.ico
      static_files: public/favicon.ico
      upload: public/favicon\.ico

    - url: /assets/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$|png$))
      static_files: public/assets/\1
      upload: public/assets/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$|png$))
      application_readable: true

    - url: /.*
      script: public/index.php
```

EDIT : Thank's to Jarmod, I've got this now :

```
        x@x:~/CuisineDeGeek$ gcloud app deploy ./app.yaml
```

Please help me.

Comment: Is your gcloud installation up to date? What happens if you invoke 'gcloud app', like it suggests, instead of 'gcloud preview app'?